# (Partial) database synchronization with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm looking for a solution with which I would be able to synchronize, upon request, a selection of tables between a live mysql database with a local database. If there is no specific solution to this, what would be a good solution for synchronizing local and live databases?

Comment: To clarify this, do you want to copy new data from tables in liveDB to tables in localDB? Do you intend to change schema of your localDB?

Comment: @Cshift3iLike The idea is to synchronize mostly data that has been added to either of the databases amongst a selection of tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is always phpmyadmin where you can export selected tables and import them again.

This is a practical solution if you have a live DB where you need to work on it with the development system. You can take a copy of the db, work on it, drop, e.g. the customer tables, then take the live offline, back it up, drop everything except the customer tables and import your updated db.

The advantage of phpmyadmin is that it shows you the queries, you can then put together a script from these and use them next time you update.

Comment: @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ Mathew, what I was looking for is something more automated or automatable (selection of tables to synchronize and then automated synchro on demand or every x days). Although I am more at the beginner end of the skills scale, I do know phpmyadmin and to me it seems to be the most manual it can get, unless there are some features I have yet to dicover.

Comment: ...yes, but it spits out SQL statements you can reliably use. These can then be put into a text file and you then run `mysql -u user -pPASSWORD database < statements.sql`. You can then put that in a cron job if you want it automated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following conditions

- Live DB can be accessed by public IP
- All Needed Tables are InnoDB

You can perform a mysqldump of individual tables

Here is how using a shell script may accomplishe this when run from the local machine:

```
LIVEDB_IP=192.168.1.10
MYSQL_SRCUSER=whateverusername
MYSQL_SRCPASS=whateverpassword
MYSQL_SRCCONN="-h${LIVEDB_IP} -u${MYSQL_SRCUSER} -p${MYSQL_SRCPASS}"
SOURCE_DB=mydb_source

MYSQL_TGTUSER=whateverusername2
MYSQL_TGTPASS=whateverpassword2
MYSQL_TGTCONN="-h127.0.0.1 -u${MYSQL_TGTUSER} -p${MYSQL_TGTPASS}"
TARGET_DB=mydb_target

TBLLIST="tb1 tb2 tb3"
for TB in `echo "${TBLLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_SRCCONN} --single-transaction ${SOURCE_DB} ${TB} | mysql ${MYSQL_TGTCONN} -A -D${TARGET_DB} &
done
wait
```

The `--single-transaction` option causes a point-in-time snapshot of the table to take place while still allowing INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs back in the source database.

If the tables are rather big, there may be timeout issues. Try this script instead:

```
LIVEDB_IP=192.168.1.10
MYSQL_SRCUSER=whateverusername
MYSQL_SRCPASS=whateverpassword
MYSQL_SRCCONN="-h${LIVEDB_IP} -u${MYSQL_SRCUSER} -p${MYSQL_SRCPASS}"
SOURCE_DB=mydb_source

MYSQL_TGTUSER=whateverusername2
MYSQL_TGTPASS=whateverpassword2
MYSQL_TGTCONN="-h127.0.0.1 -u${MYSQL_TGTUSER} -p${MYSQL_TGTPASS}"
TARGET_DB=mydb_target

TBLLIST="tb1 tb2 tb3"
for TB in `echo "${TBLLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_SRCCONN} --single-transaction ${SOURCE_DB} ${TB} | gzip > ${TB}.sql.gz &
done
wait

for TB in `echo "${TBLLIST}"`
do
    gzip -d < ${TB}.sql.gz | mysql ${MYSQL_TGTCONN} -A -D${TARGET_DB} &
done
wait
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

If the tables needed are MyISAM, just remove `--single-transaction` from the mysqldump. This may cause queries at the source database to freeze until the the mysqldump is done with the tables the queries need. In that event, just perform this script during low traffic hours.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop db manager [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) has a "[Job Scheduler](http://webyog.com/faq/content/27/114/en/introduction-to-the-_sqlyog-job-agent_-sja.html)" tool for setting up things like this. It requires a professional or enterprise license(cheaper than they sound), but the 30-day trial is full-featured if you just want to check it out first.